# doOnSubscribe Method never called

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java

I have a network call in Android with Retrofit and RxJava that looks like this:

```
m_VerifyVersionCommObj = m_MultiplayerRound.testServerVersion()
                .doOnSubscribe { ::startProgressDialog }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .delay (1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ) //TODO: to remove this
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnTerminate { ::stopProgressDialog }
                .doOnComplete { ::stopProgressDialog }
                .subscribe({data -> checkServerVersion(data.body())}
                    , {error -> error.localizedMessage?.let { showError(it) } })
```

startProgressDialog is a function in the same class where the call is made that simply shows a loader. Sadly the loader does not show. I have also debugged this and the method is not called. To the opposite the method in doOnTerminate and doOnComplete is called. The network call is also completed.

The observable is created like this:

```
fun testServerVersion(): Observable<Response<VersionResponse>> {
    return m_Service.getVersion()
}

@POST("status/getversion")
     @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
     fun getVersion(): Observable<retrofit2.Response<VersionResponse>>
```

Can anyone please give a hint on how to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried moving `doOnSubscribe { ::startProgressDialog }` right before the subscribe?

Comment: If you are getting `doOnComplete` but not `doOnSubscribe` and you don't have anything in between that would stop the flow prematurely, it is likely the `m_Service.getVersion()` is implemented incorrectly and violates the observable contract.

Comment: @WilsonCastiblanco I have tried like that but it still does not work.

Comment: I have found the answer. I have changed the doOnSubscribe clause to .doOnSubscribe { startProgressDialog() } and it works now.